Issues Converting PDF to Images in Node.js on Google Cloud Functions
I've been trying to convert PDF files to images using various methods and packages in Node.js. While the code works fine locally, it fails when deployed to Google Cloud Functions. I want to convert a pdf into images. Each page of pdf must be converted into an image.
I am using Node.js 20 and Mac M1.
I have used many npm packages like pdf2pic, pdf2image, pdf-lib, canvas, gm etc. Here are the details:
pdf-image: Works locally fine but fails on Google Cloud Functions
gm (GraphicsMagick): Code works locally but fails on Google Cloud Functions with error: Command failed: convert-im6.q16: not authorized ...
pdf2pic: Works locally but fails on Google Cloud Functions with error
**pdf-lib**: Attempted to use PDFDocument and renderToBuffer, but these methods are not suitable for rendering pages as images
**canvas**: Required for some PDF rendering libraries, but it's not supported in my environment
**pdf-poppler**: Tried using pdf-poppler for conversion. 

Faced issues with deploying the compiled binaries required for pdf-poppler
Of all these packages, i found pdf-image easy to use and perfect for my use case but it fails on gcp.
Code using gm:
gm(pdfPath + '[0]')
        .density(150)
        .write(imagePath, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error converting PDF to image:', err);
                res.status(500).json({
                    flag: false,
                    message: 'Error converting PDF to image',
                    error: err
                });
                return;
            }

            console.log(`Image created at path (${imagePath}) exists: ${fs.existsSync(imagePath)}`);
            res.status(200).json({
                flag: true,
                message: "Conversion successful",
                imagePath: imagePath
            });
        });

Code using pdf-image:
var pdfImage = new PDFImage(pdfPath,{combinedImage: true});
const imagePaths = await pdfImage.convertFile();


Can you share additional error from GCP console? Also can you share code you are using to convert PDF to image.

When i used pdf-image npm package, it did not show any error and it got crashed when the code to convert pdf to image came. But when is used gm npm package which uses imagick to convert pdf into image. I got the following error: Error: Command failed: convert-im6.q16: not authorized `/tmp/downloaded_file.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined

Can you check this thread1 & thread2?
